# Get Facebook comments from a non-Facebook site URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

Is there still a way to get Facebook comments from a site URL using Graph API?
I tried converting a site URL to an object-id, but it failed using Graph API Explorer.
Some older posts mention using `/{object-id}/comments`, some mention `?id=https://she.hr/nevjerojatni-spoj-dragocjenih-bisera-i-pouzdane-njege-uz-nivea-pearlbeauty-black-antiperspiranate/&fields=og_object{comments{message,from{name,%20picture}}}`

But I couldn't get a single comment.

I also found fb_comment_id in comments' IFRAME, but couldn't get data on that one either on Graph API explorer (using /{comment_id}).

Comment: I can't find this mentioned any more on the documentation page of the comments plugin - but I am pretty sure it was mentioned there in the past, which probably means Facebook has removed this by now. And https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v14.0/url doesn't mention `comments` below `og_object` any more either, it looks like you can only get the _count_ now, as part of `engagement`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, I guess I can still try using headless browser to scrape the IFRAME of the comments, and hope people don't post too much on this site during the scrape process.